# Water main pressure speed

Tags: pressure

In a long fire service water main under pressure, say 10 Km long,  for street hydrants, if the farthest one of street hydrants open, what is the time lag  the pressure drop can be detected by the pressure sensor installed in the fire water pumping station. My question is will any time delay due to long distance between the pressure sensor in the pumping station and the farthest end of water main.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear to me, but I think the speed you are seeking is equal to speed of sound in water.

Comment: Speed of sound may be slightly affected by the elasticity of the pipe.   Bulk water and water in a pipe are different sound-propogation media.

Comment: Please elaborate and post it as an answer.